# What's the connection between the concepts of field and $\sigma$-field

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am learning probability theory now and our probability theory course is built upon the measure theory. In the first class, we talked about the concept of field and $\sigma$-field. One property of $\sigma$-field that we have been introduced is if $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-field, it is a field. In my opinion, the field must be a subtype of the field. In other words, if we consider all types of field, a portion of them may be considered as $\sigma$-field. However, in later class when we were briefly introduced with the concept of measure, our teacher tried to give us a general picture of what we have done so far.

He said that $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$ is a measurable space provided that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-field of subset of $\Omega$. Then he went on saying that when mathematician tries to find the proper class for measurable space they realize only a field would be inadequate. He then went on saying that $\sigma$-field is a larger class compared to a field.

I am very confused at this point as I thought $\sigma$-field must be a smaller class as compared to the field. I am not even sure if these two concepts can be compared using the langue of "large" or "small". I read another post today [What are the foundations of probability and how are they dependent upon a  σ -field?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206778/common-ground-between-real-analysis-and-measure-theory) which gives an answer "No" to the relationship between the $\sigma$-field and a field, which made me more bewildered.

I understand that my understanding of a field is very rudimentary as I am not coming from a mathematical background. I hope my naïve way of understanding of the relationship between a field and $\sigma$-field can reveal the misconceptions I have in mind. In this post, I mainly expect someone to explain to me the relationship between a field and a $\sigma$-field in a broader sense (not that if a class is a $\sigma$-field it must also be a field). For example, why we give so much attention to $\sigma$-field. What are the implications of the difference between the condition "countably infinite union"? (What will happen if we don't make such distinction?)

Comment: If you read the comments under the answer, you’ll find that Qiaochu was assuming that the OP was using *field* in the abstract algebra sense, so that *no* is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed all $\sigma$-fields are fields. This was not what was meant by "larger class" by your teacher. Also, the answer "no" by Qiaochu Yuan was saying that $\sigma$-fields are not fields in the sense of algebra; they are indeed fields of sets.

Anyway, a $\sigma$-field "typically" will need to have "more sets" in it than a field would; in particular, you can ask for the minimal $\sigma$-field containing a given field, and typically it will be a proper superset of the field you started with.

Within probability theory you only really care about $\sigma$-fields and can essentially ignore the notion of fields. In real analysis there is a bit more going on because we want to build things like the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ "without doing too much work" so we come up with slick tricks of extending the Lebesgue measure restricted to "rather small" subsets of the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra (in real analysis the term "$\sigma$-algebra" is considerably more common).

Comment: I cannot recall the exact wording my teacher said so it is more like how I understood what he said and reinterpreted in ways that make sense to myself. The second paragraph may be what my teacher meant. Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: In set theory a field is defined as closed under finite unions and intersections.  The point is that if it is closed only under these operations, it is not adequate for measure theory.

Answer (score 0):

As in many other circumstances in mathematics, trying to list a couple of good examples helps you clarify two connected while different concepts. Let's consider the following example.

Let $\mathcal{A}$ consist of the finite and the cofinite sets (a set $A$ is cofinite if $A^c$ is finite). Then $\mathcal{A}$ is a field (straightforward to verify by definition). If $\Omega$ is finite, then $\mathcal{A}$ contains all the subsets of $\Omega$ hence is a $\sigma$-field as well. If $\Omega$ is infinite, however, then $\mathcal{A}$ is not a $\sigma$-field. For instance, choose a sequence $\omega_1, \omega_2, \ldots$ of distinct points in $\Omega$ and take $A = \{\omega_2, \omega_4, \ldots\}$. Then $A \notin \mathcal{A}$, even though $A$ is the union, necessarily countable, of the singletons it contains and each singleton is in $\mathcal{A}$. This example shows that the definition of $\sigma$-field is indeed more restrictive that of field.

On the other hand, a $\sigma$-field must be a field (again, check the definition). In this sense, it makes sense to say $\sigma$-field is always "larger" than a field.

To your second question, here is a perspective. In probability, we are interested in evaluating the uncertainty (i.e., probability) of certain "events". Probabilistically speaking, the collection of all those events made up of the "$\mathcal{A}$" in the probability space triple $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$. While it is OK to study many interesting problems with a field $\mathcal{A}$ (say, the classic/discrete probability space), it is of particular interest to study some event which is a countably infinite union of some basic events. As a famous example (the so-called *Borel's normal number theorem*), consider throwing a coin perpetually, the event of those outcomes for which the asymptotic relative frequency of head in the infinite sequence of heads and tails is $\frac{1}{2}$. While this event cannot be formulated as finite union/intersection of simpler events given $\mathcal{A}$ is a field, it is expressible as a countably infinite unions/intersections of simpler events given $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-field. You might have heard many celebrated theorems in probability, such as weak/strong law of large numbers, central limit theorem, etc., which all rely on the assumption that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-field instead of merely being a field.